# Refining results based on criteria

Tags: php, mysql, database, ajax

Hey I'm trying to look at how I would refine results based on criteria.

The idea is, for example when you have movie theatre I want people to answer 10 questions, where each Question has 2 answers like:
Thriller/Horror
Kids/Adult
Foreign/Local

etc etc, and when people choose theire criteria, the script returns movies that are close to those criteria in let's say a top 5 list.

So I imagine you'd need to predefine stuff to the movies on which the script can match the criteria and whenever a movie has the most matches it comes up as the top one.

Does anybody know a script or a way to begin?

Thanks if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Use [tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_%28metadata%29). The movies that match the most tags selected by the user are displayed.

You'd have three tables, `movies`, `tags` and `movies_tags` (cross-reference).

Comment: Thanks for the help, sounds good.
And what would the movies_tags hold for data?

So what would be the best combination.
I assume using, PHP and mysql to compare and read the data.
Then maybe Ajax to return and show the results in a fancy manner?